# How do I implement a DShow filter for reading specialized AVI file

Tags: filter, directshow, avi, winapi

I'm trying to write DirectShow filter which will read file containts some xml-data at the beginning and avi video after it. I'm going open a file in the filter, skip the xml-data and begin the playback. I found in the Windows SDK the example which played BMP-file (Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\filters\pushsource).  Where can I spy out how do I read avi frames, convert ones and push it in an output pin? 
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can find AVI file specs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave#External_links). But there is an easier solution: use standard AVI Splitter filter which is part of DirectShow. Just take another sample filter from SDK - Async and make it read your XML data and then act as a regular file source but reading data from your file with some shifted offset. This way all the parsing work will be done by AVI Splitter and all your filter needs to do is reading parts of file that Splitter requests.